# A descriptive cake

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern

A 'geezer' walks into a bakery. The man is covered from top to bottom with tattoos - on his face, on his shoulders... even arrow tattoos on his fingers. He has dropped by to hand in a design for a specially decorated cake, but has forgotten two of the numbers that should be on it...

> **Can you help him figure out which numbers he forgot?** (Knowing his hobbies would certainly make it easier!)

[image]

**Hint:**

> His hobby is *at the tips of his fingers*... (This doesn't help you with the cipher itself but does provide you with an ordering for the numbers you see. After deciphering, this will lead to a sentence which will lead you to the two missing numbers!)

Comment: I'm thinking his hobby might be rot13(qnegf), but looking at a rot(qnegf obneq) did not yet help me with the cipher.

Comment: rot13(lbh'er dhvgr evtug nobhg uvf ubool, V nqqrq n uvag pbapreavat guvf ubool.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer

> Top ? is 1010 and the bottom-right ? is 108

First,

> Note that the numbers are arranged similar to a dartboard. This allows us to reorder the numbers to get the following: (/ denotes a space)
>  ? 107 71 71 99 108 76 95 / ? 92 / 77 106 / 96 109 75 75 106

Breaking the code

> With a bit of luck, I noticed that the first word could be PUZZLING. This gave a rather curious correlation - Z=71, N=76, G=95, L=99, U=107, and I=108. Notably, ZN are the bottom row of keys on a QWERTY keyboard, GL are the middle row, and UI are the top row.
>  Also, Z is to the left of the N by 5 spaces, G is left of L by 4 spaces, and U is left of I by one space. In fact if you draw a line from each letter diagonally up-left, you intercept the same digit key as the units digit.
>  The 7, 9, and 10 can be explained as the bottom row has 7 letters, the middle row has 9 letters, and the top row has 10 letters.
>  Armed with this, we can fill in the rest of the message: **?uzzling ?s my hobby.**
>  Therefore, we need the values for P* (corresponding to 1 and at the top) and I (which corresponds to 10 and bottom right). For I, we know its value - 108. P is 1010, by concatenating the number of keys in its row, with the order from left to right (so qwertyuiop is 101, 102, 103, ..., 109, 1010).
>  *I suppose puzzling could be some other word like nuzzling, guzzling, or muzzling, but it seems the most contextually appropriate :P

Explanation of hint

> Arrow tattoos on the fingers, with the clue "at the tips of his fingers" suggests that 1) arrows to suggest darts and looking at a dartboard, and 2) typing could be a hobby as well, since that definitely involves the fingers. The arrows could also help motivate looking at the number row as well.

Comment: I think you're right about all of this. However, I'd really love to know exactly why each 'row' would start counting at 71, 91 and 101 - and why no 81?? That's the logic I'm missing here (though I think you've nailed the rest of it...)

Comment: The first hint is used properly. You're in the right direction with deciphering, unfortunately the answer is not completely correct yet.

Comment: Ok, I think I can explain the 7, 9, and 10 now, and maybe the other interpretation that I floated in the explanation was actually correct.

Comment: You're explanation is quite correct, but your derivation of one of the ? is wrong.

Comment: Is P 1010 instead?

Comment: @phenomist rot13(Wrc gung'f vg! Abj obgu ? ner pbeerpg, punatr vg va lbhe nafjre naq V jvyy npprcg lbhe nafjre.)